# Get Titanium.App.Properties in another win or make it global available

Tags: javascript, properties, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Please don’t answer this if you don’t take the time to understand my question or have a reasonable answer. I have got a few answers that is far on the side and I think I explain my problem very clear. Shall this problem drive me nuts or is there somebody out there with a straight and clear answer on Titanium.App.Properties?

I have a login form that stores the username in one:

> Titanium.App.Properties.setString("userName",e.value);

and the password in another:

> Titanium.App.Properties.setString("passWord",e.value);

The forms TextFields holds these values(after a store) even if I close the window, shut down and restarts the app. This because of the App.Properties.getString("value"); I suppose….?!
But when I copy the hole form with its App.Properties.getString("value"); to another window, the TextFields are empty and contains no value at all. I understand that the Properties string must be there some where in App.Properties, but how can grab it and use it another place in the app?

My question is: How to get the value from my

> var userNameValue = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("userNameValue");

to be available in another window or for the hole app(global)? How can I grab it and make use of it a another place in the app? I don’t see a good reason to make these, only separate words, into objects(JSON) since the userName only contains a e-mail address and the passWord consist only of continuing letters or numbers. But if you mean I have too, -how do I set this from my TextField and get it in another TextField  somewhere else in my app. I have not had any luck so far. I hope you can help me out and I can keep sane.

Answer (score 1):

> Titanium.App.Properties.getString("userNameValue");

This is globally Available, any Propertie of the Titanium Object is accessible in each file.

but if for some reason this doesnt work for you and you want to set a global variable,
you could do the following:

- Create a file called myGlobals.js //or anything else,

> //Put this in there e.g
>      var myProperties = {};

- in any file you want to use it write in the first line

> ```
> Ti.include('myGlobals.js');
> ```

Then you can make  a propertie global available, for example write this in app.js somewhere where the app initializes

> myProperties.Username = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("userName");

Then you can get the value in each file by accesing the propertie
myProperties.Username

> ```
> //of course the Propertie has to be set before you can get them
> ( Titanium.App.Properties.setString("userName",e.value); ) //like you do it
> ```

But, Titanium.App.Properties.getString("userName");
should be avilable from any file anyway, (but you can give this a try although i dont think its nice to do it like this)

i had a similar problem where this didnt get any value from a propertie set in the ios settings as default value.

I had to go to the settings and manually change or edit the default value and then after a restart

> Titanium.App.Properties.getString("userName"); 
>   returned the value as it should,
>   i hope this helps you =)

### Answer to the Comment

I'm glad i could help you =)

Yes you can Use an focus EventHandler like this :

```
textfield.addEventListener("focus",function(){
textfield.value = "Test"; 
});
```

Beside that , are you using the identical Textfield for both windows ? like

```
var Textfield = Ti.Ui.createTextField({...});
```

and add it to 2 different windows ?

```
win1.add(Textfield);
win2.add(Textfield);
```

That led for me to Problems with labels in TableViewRows, using an identical Row 2 times in the TableView

The Text displayed only on 1 Label, sometimes it switched the Labels
I think you can't add one and the same titanium object to more then one other object

Maybe that could be the culprit,
dunno just an idea =)

Comment: Thank you so very much, it was very helpful. The problem seems to be that the form duplicate that is on another win does not refresh or update with the new values from the getString -before the app is totally restarted(shut down). Is there any method to force a textField update on win 'focus' so the values in getString can appear instantly in those textFields?

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I wish i could vote one more time. Many Thanks.